# Processing csv file using shell script

Tags: shell, csv

I have a csv file with fields:
'file path', 'line no', 'description'.  For example:

```
/home/user/file.txt,121,xxxx
```

The csv file has many entries. 
How do I parse fields file path and line no and store them? 
After I parse the file path I have to open the file in a Linux machine  and `grep` for a particular string. 
Can someone give me an idea how to do it?

Steps are:

1. Open csv file.
2. Find file name and line number.
3. Open that file and line number.
4. Grep for some pattern.
5. Continue steps 2,3,4 in that csv file.

Comment: Please add example of CSV file with sample text.

Comment: /home/user/file.txt,121,xxxx

Comment: so do you want to grep something on line number 121 of /home/user/file.txt

Comment: Please update the question with the extra information rather than adding comments.  And if you do add information from a comment to the question, please delete the comment.  Thanks.

Comment: Where does the pattern that you're searching for come from?  Is it the 'description' in the CSV file, or does it come from somewhere else?  You say 'open that file and line number' and then 'grep for some pattern'; does that mean you want to detect whether that pattern appears on the given line of the given file (and you don't care whether the pattern appears anywhere else in the file)?

Comment: Pattern appears on the given line

Comment: I want to detect whether the pattern appears on the given line of the given file. Pattern is some string eg:"error"

Answer (score 0):

```
cat sample.csv
home/user1/file1.txt,2,nice user1

cat home/user1/file1.txt
PATTERN1
PATTERN3
PATTERN2
PATTERN4
```

#### Main Script

```
   #Run till the last line of the file is reached.
while read line
do

#Capture the line number which is in 2nd column

line_number=$(echo $line |awk -F, '{print $2}')

#Capture the file name which is in 1st column

file_name=$(echo $line |awk -F, '{print $1}')

#echo each line and print the line in corresponding file and grep for PATTERN

cat $file_name |head -n $line_number |tail -1 |grep PATTERN

done <sample.csv
```

Comment: echo $line |head -$line_number |tail -1 |grep Pattern.. What does this line do? Can you please explain?

Comment: added comments, Example:  "head -5 and tail -1" will print 5th line.  does it help ?

Comment: It doesnt work.. Should it be echo $filename |head -$line_number |tail -1 |xargs grep PATTERN

Comment: Looks right.. But I keep getting error head: option requires an argument  - - 'n'

Comment: not sure , why its not working for you. ,  this may help .try changing the like like "cat $file_name |head -$line_number |tail -1 |grep PATTERN"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111628/discussion-between-randomuser-and-user1495948).